# formatting the date as year only after resampling in pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, pivot, dataframe

I resampled a dataframe of stock data using the following:

```
pivot = c.pivot("date","stock_name","close").resample("A",how="ohlc")
```

I am wondering how can you format the output so that the dates appear as `YYYY` e.g. `2016` not `YYYY-MM-DD` like `1969-12-31`

Comment: you can use `pivot.index = pivot.index.year` or use  [strftime](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html)